# WinAPI - Menu accelerators not working

Tags: c++, winapi, menu, resources, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to add accelerators to my menu, when I press 'Ctrl+R' it should send the command `ID_VIEW_RESULTS`, But it doesn't. It works fine clicking the menu item, but it isn't translating the accelerator, this is what I have:

MyApp.h

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>

#define ID_MAINMENU 101
#define ID_MENUACC  102

#define ID_VIEW_RESULTS 2001
```

MyApp.rc

```
#include "MyApp.h"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Menu
//

ID_MAINMENU MENU 
BEGIN
    POPUP "&View"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "Calculated &Results...\aCtrl+R",  ID_VIEW_RESULTS
    END
END

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Accelerator
//

ID_MENUACC ACCELERATORS 
BEGIN
    "^R",       ID_VIEW_RESULTS,        ASCII,  NOINVERT
END
```

MyApp.cpp

```
#include "MyApp.h"

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInst);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // Create and show main window, CMainWnd definition is dialog
    // resource template, works fine, irrelevant to problem.
    MainWnd = new CMainWnd();
    MainWnd->Show();

    MSG    Msg;
    HACCEL hAcc;
    hAcc = LoadAccelerators(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID_MENUACC));

    while (GetMessage(&Msg, 0, 0, 0)) {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(Msg.hwnd, hAcc, &Msg)) {
            TranslateMessage(&Msg);
            DispatchMessage(&Msg);
        }
    }

    return (int)Msg.wParam;
}
```

I myself can't see a good reason why this wouldn't work, can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong or give me any suggestions?

Comment: Try replacing Msg.hwnd with the HWND member of MainWnd. If that works than Msg.hwnd is not the right window that gets the message (in Tanslate Accelerator parameters).

Comment: @Edwin That worked perfectly, thank you. I knew it had to be something simple. Anyways, you should post that as an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: done ! glad it worked out that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing Msg.hwnd with the HWND member of MainWnd. If that works than Msg.hwnd is not the right window that gets the message (in Tanslate Accelerator parameters).